# Spark deduplication of RDD to get bigger RDD

Tags: duplicates, pyspark, union

I have a dataframe loaded from disk

```
df_ = sqlContext.read.json("/Users/spark_stats/test.json")
```

It contains 500k rows.
my script works fine on this size, but I want to test it for example on 5M rows, is there a way to duplicate the df 9 times? (it does not matter for me to have duplicates in the df)

i already use union but it is really too slow (as I think it keeps reading from the disk everytime)

```
df = df_
for i in range(9): 
    df = df.union(df_)
```

Do you have an idea about a clean way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: use .cache() once you read from the data source.

Comment: Thank you, thank worked just fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode.  It should only read from the raw disk once:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

schema = StructType([StructField("f1", StringType()), StructField("f2", StringType())])

data = [("a", "b"), ("c", "d")]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

# Create an array with as many values as times you want to duplicate the rows
dups_array = [lit(i) for i in xrange(9)]
duplicated = df.withColumn("duplicate", array(*dups_array)) \
               .withColumn("duplicate", explode("duplicate")) \
               .drop("duplicate")
```