# Convert JSON using PySpark and data frame to have array elements under root

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I want to reorganise the following JSON so that array elements under docs will be under root.

Example input

```
{
  "response":{"docs":
      [{
        "column1":"dataA",
        "column2":"dataB"
      },  
      {
        "column1":"dataC",
        "column2":"dataD"
      }]
   }
}
```

Example PySpark script

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf


conf = SparkConf().setAppName("pyspark")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.json("file:///.../input.json", multiLine=True)
new = df.select("response.docs")
new.printSchema()
new.write.mode("overwrite").format('json').save("file:///.../output.json")
```

The script already converts the schema to the following

```
root
 |-- docs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- column1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- column2: string (nullable = true)
```

However, it should look like this final JSON

```
[
 {"column1":"dataA","column2":"dataB"},
 {"column1":"dataC","column2":"dataD"}
]
```

How can this be done using Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode the `response.docs` column.
Then just select `column1` and `column2` from this exploded column.
Like this

```
df.select(F.explode('response.docs').alias('col')) \
  .select('col.column1', 'col.column2')
```

Then the result will be like this

```
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|  dataA|  dataB|
|  dataC|  dataD|
+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [explode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#explode) Spark function (see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436856/explode-array-data-into-rows-in-spark))

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. However, seems like df.select(explode(df.response.docs)) will also create a new column called "col".

Comment: You just need to select needed columns afterwards