# How to de-serialize the spark data frame into another data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am trying to de-serialize the the spark data frame into another data frame as expected below.

Existing Dataframe Data:

[image]

Existing Dataframe schema:

[image]

Expected Dataframe:

[image]

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explode array data into rows in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436856/explode-array-data-into-rows-in-spark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [explode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#explode) function for that.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode 
df.withColumn("ns2:fileName", explode(df.ns2:fileName))
```

**EDIT**

```
df.withColumn("result", explode(zip($"ns2:fileName", $"ns2:alias"))).select(
   $"result._1".alias("ns2:fileName"), $"result._2".alias("ns2:alias"))
```

Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220916/explode-transpose-multiple-columns-in-spark-sql-table).

Comment: i tried but its throwing below error
NameError: name 'explode' is not defined

Comment: I edited my question. But please check the duplicate question for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but wheni try to explode only one column, im able to do and i can see the the data correctly for first column but the second column is not exploded and tried the below code
```
project_processed_df1 = project_raw_df.withColumn("ProjectId", explode(project_raw_df.ProjectId)).withColumn("ProjectDesc", explode(project_raw_df.ProjectDesc))
```
The above code explode both the columns but it generated many to many relation and making wrong data.
Any idea?

Comment: You can zip both array columns and explode the result of the zip. I edited my answer