# How to improve Spark SQL query performance over DataFrame that has array columns?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Let's say I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`, which have many array type columns. Some of the columns can have `null` values.

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("temp1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("temp2")
```

I am using `LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE` to flatten the array type columns. Following is an example Spark SQL statement that I am using to query over dataframes. This query seems to have a performance issue because of the `LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE`.

```
SELECT tab1.id AS country, tab2.city_lve AS city FROM
(SELECT id, language_lve, population_lve FROM temp1
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(language) EXPLODED_NAMES AS language_lve
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(population) EXPLODED_NAMES AS population_lve
WHERE language_lve IS NOT NULL AND population_lve IS NOT NULL)
AS tab1
JOIN
(SELECT id, city_lve, link_lve FROM temp2
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(city) EXPLODED_NAMES AS city_lve
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(link) EXPLODED_NAMES AS link_lve
WHERE city_lve IS NOT NULL AND link_lve IS NOT NULL)
AS tab2 ON (tab2.link_lve = tab1.language_lve)
```

Is there any efficinent Spark SQL statement to query over the dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

**Explode** will solve your case

Below is an example from a different question using it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44418598/1461187

Comment: I am already using `Explode` in my Spark SQL statement. I am looking for a better solution.